# Code which replicates an equation for a fixed value annuity not giving the correct answer

Tags: c#, finance

I am building a finance calculator of sorts and one part I am developing is finding the future value for a fixed annuity. The equation for a regular annuity (i.e. payment at the end of the period) is:

`PMT/i * ((1+i)^n - 1) * (1+iT)`

Where `PMT` is the payment per period `t`, `i = r/m` is the growth rate `r` divided by the times compounded per period `m`, `n` is the number of compounded periods `m*t`, and `T` is a `0` or `1` valued variable which indicated whether it is a ordinary or due annuity.

My method for the specific function is:

```cs
public static decimal FutureFixedAnnuityValue(decimal annuity, float time, float interest, int nCompPeriods = 1, int startImmediately = 0)
{
    return annuity / (decimal)interest * (decimal)(Math.Pow(1 + interest / nCompPeriods, time * nCompPeriods) - 1) * (decimal)(1 + interest / nCompPeriods * startImmediately);
}
```

Over here, `PMT = annuity, t = time, r = interest, m = nCompPeriods, T = startImmediately`.

To collect the parameters, I use this button click method:

```cs
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal payment = decimal.Parse(txtAnnuity.Text); //PMT
    int periods = int.Parse(txtPeriods.Text); //t
    float gain = float.Parse(txtEnterInterest.Text) / 100; //r
    float length = float.Parse(txtEnterYears.Text); //m
    int immediately = chkPaymentAt.Checked ? 1 : 0; //due or ordinary

    decimal afv = FinanceCalculations.FutureFixedAnnuityValue(payment, length, gain, periods, immediately);
    lblAnnuityFixed.Text = afv.ToString("C2");
}
```

To test if my method works I use this online calculator: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/future-value-annuity-calculator.php.

With the arguments `PMT = 1000, t = 10, r = 1, m = 12, T = 0`, my application gives `$10 512.49`, but the calculator gives `$10 464.39`. However, if I change `m = 1` my application and the calculator both give `$10 462.21`.

I don't know what is causing this disparity. I have tried changing `annuity / (decimal)interest` to `annuity / (decimal)(interest/nCompPeriods)` but that intuitively doesn't make sense because lowering the denominator even further increases the output more, and testing it confirms my suspicion since my output becomes `$126 149.88`.

So what is going on? I can't figure what is causing the difference. It seems like it has to do with something regarding the denominator of the `annuity / (decimal)interest`, but I just don't know what it can be.

Comment: Split each step, then use your debugger to spot where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem. It has to do with the fact that the payment frequencies do not coincide with the number of compounding periods. When that happens `r` must be recalculated to find an effective rate with the [equation found here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/equivalent-interest-rate-calculator.php). Then, the payment frequencies (referred to as `q`) take the place of `m`, and `i` and `n` are recalculated with `q` instead of `m`.

When that is done, the error is fixed. I have added a `paymentFrequency` integer parameter to my function that checks if `nCompPeriods` is the same as `paymentFrequency`. If they match, then the original calculation is sufficient, otherwise `interest` must be turned into another effective rate and `paymentFrequency` takes the place of `nCompPeriods`.